# When using Secure Boot can other drives still be MBR?

Tags: windows-10, formatting, windows-installation, secure-boot

I recently read:

> If Secure Boot is enabled in BIOS, then your System will need your hard drive to be GPT …

But what about the other drives? Can they still be MBR?

Comment: Whatever you read only applies to the system disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Secure boot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-secure-boot)
is only relevant to verifying the boot software.
It works with both MBR and GPT devices.

The constraints are actually that of the firmware: UEFI needs GPT
(except in Legacy mode), while BIOS needs MBR.

As a GPT disk has a fake MBR header, it can work with a device that
requires MBR (with limitations).

Devices which are not boot devices don't have any constraints
and can be either MBR or GPT, as supported by the operating system.